# HTML image and text align vertically if resized

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to display an image and a text to the right of it. I use the code:

```css
div.out {
  background-color: silver;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

div.right {
  order: 1;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/asXsj.jpg" width="40%" height="60%">
  <div class="right">
    A rose is a woody perennial flowering plant of the genus Rosa, in the family Rosaceae, or the flower it bears. There are over a hundred species and thousands of cultivars. They form a group of plants that can be erect shrubs, climbing or trailing with
    stems that are often armed with sharp prickles. Flowers vary in size and shape and are usually large and showy, in colours ranging from white through yellows and reds. Most species are native to Asia, with smaller numbers native to Europe, North America,
    and northwestern Africa. Species, cultivars and hybrids are all widely grown for their beauty and often are fragrant. Roses have acquired cultural significance in many societies. Rose plants range in size from compact, miniature roses, to climbers
    that can reach seven meters in height. Different species hybridize easily, and this has been used in the development of the wide range of garden roses.
  </div>
</div>
```

When I resize the window horizontally then both the image and the text resize accordingly. Which is fine but I want to add one more fact. If the image is to be resized below let's say `250x250` pixels then it should not drop below `250x250` but the text instead to appear below of it. Example:

[image]

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the screen size the flexbox should wrap or not. Make sure the browser is instructed on how to handle the viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

```css
div.out {
  background-color: silver;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

div.right {
  order: 1;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .out {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/asXsj.jpg" width="40%" height="60%">
  <div class="right">
    A rose is a woody perennial flowering plant of the genus Rosa, in the family Rosaceae, or the flower it bears. There are over a hundred species and thousands of cultivars. They form a group of plants that can be erect shrubs, climbing or trailing with
    stems that are often armed with sharp prickles. Flowers vary in size and shape and are usually large and showy, in colours ranging from white through yellows and reds. Most species are native to Asia, with smaller numbers native to Europe, North America,
    and northwestern Africa. Species, cultivars and hybrids are all widely grown for their beauty and often are fragrant. Roses have acquired cultural significance in many societies. Rose plants range in size from compact, miniature roses, to climbers
    that can reach seven meters in height. Different species hybridize easily, and this has been used in the development of the wide range of garden roses.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media Query which screen size what you need like

```
@media(max-width:320px){
  .out img { width:100%; }
  .right { width:100%; float:left; }
}
```

Comment: yeah , thanks for your information i just show him a demo with media query

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to display an image and a text to the right of it. I use the code:

```css
div.out {
  background-color: silver;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

div.right {
  position: relative;
  order: 1;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/asXsj.jpg" width="40%" height="60%">
    <ul id="list"></ul>
    <div id="similar" class="right">
      A rose is a woody perennial flowering plant of the genus Rosa, in the family Rosaceae, or the flower it bears. There are over a hundred species and thousands of cultivars. They form a group of plants that can be erect shrubs, climbing or trailing with
      stems that are often armed with sharp prickles. Flowers vary in size and shape and are usually large and showy, in colours ranging from white through yellows and reds. Most species are native to Asia, with smaller numbers native to Europe, North
      America, and northwestern Africa. Species, cultivars and hybrids are all widely grown for their beauty and often are fragrant. Roses have acquired cultural significance in many societies. Rose plants range in size from compact, miniature roses,
      to climbers that can reach seven meters in height. Different species hybridize easily, and this has been used in the development of the wide range of garden roses.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this example can help you.

```css
.sample {
  clear: both;
}
.sample img {
  max-width: 350px;
  float:left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.sample p {
  float:none;
}

.sample1 {
  clear: both;
}
.sample1 div {
  display:inline-block;
}
.sample1 img {
  max-width: 350px;
  dispaly:inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.sample1 p {
    dispaly:inline-block;
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample">
  <img src="http://f9view.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/What-is-Beauty-of-Nature-Description-Pictures-3.jpg" alt="">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
<br><hr>
<div class="sample1">
 <div>
  <img src="http://f9view.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/What-is-Beauty-of-Nature-Description-Pictures-3.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div>
    <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </p>

 </div>
```